# Convert subsections of array of char to int

Tags: c

Is there a `strtol()` or `sscanf()` equivalent where you can specify the no. of chars to convert?

I have a use case where I need to convert sub sections of an array of chars to ints, so I don't have the terminating null char present

In other words, I'd like the equivalent of `strncmp()` in relation to `strcmp()`

i.e. `strntol()` or `snscanf()` but they don't seem to exist

I imagine i'll just have to copy and append a `'\0'` and use `strtol()` or `sscanf()` but just wanted to check I hadn't missed an existing function for this purpose

question is really do they exist? am i just searching for the wrong thing?

Comment: Might the subsection contain white-space characters?  Are white-spaces handled just like other characters?

Comment: @chux: good point, I cannot think of a simple solution if white-space in included in the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent for `strtol`, but you can use format specifier to limit the number of characters considered by `sscanf`:

```
char *str = "1234567890";
int n;
sscanf(&str[3], "%3d", &n);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

The `%3d` specifier instructs `sscanf` to take only three digits from `str`, while `&str[3]` tells `sscanf` to start at the index `3`.

The above code prints `456` ([demo](https://ideone.com/KC3TvE)).

Comment: forgot to add the char array is in hex, its effectively a byte stream - would i be right in thinking sscanf(&str[3], "%3x", &n); is the correct mod?

Comment: @bph Yes, assuming that this is a hex-formatted stream of bytes representing `int`s from the most significant to the least significant digit, then all you need to do is replacing `%3d` with `%3x`, and changing `n` to `unsigned` ([demo](https://ideone.com/fGGOKU)).

Comment: IIRC, the 3 does not include whitespace, so with `"%d"`, `"\t\t12345"` converts to 123 and not 1.

Comment: Good solution. For clarity, I would add a check on the return value:  `if (sscanf(&str[3], "%3d", &n) == 1) { printf("%d\n", n); }` and use a different number for the offset and the number of characters.

Comment: for sure, my sscanfs are encased in if statements - good practice i think